# Downloads from Firefox

Tags: firefox, downloads

As of Yesterday My Firefox Downloads are failing consistently for no apparent reason. Chromium works and Firefox works on my windows machine.
Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Did it get upgraded yesterday? What makes you think it’s failed? (I know that appears to be a silly question but what happens when you try to download?)

Comment: It may be another issue with recent Firefox update (98.0). Until now, there were several bugs with this release. For example, all my MIME type associations in Firefox were lost and have been forced to "download the file". I had to set them again.

Comment: See: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/98.0/releasenotes/ Firefox version 98 has changed the way downloads work in an unintuitively way (IMHO).

Comment: 98,Yes,The downloads say Failed and retries fail also. Have read the release notes changed option to choose a folder. It still doesn't work. I think it's something to do with Ubuntu installing as a flat pack.I did have the" setting controlled by your organisation" note in settings but it now seems to have disappeared

Comment: I have problems with the Ubuntu-firefox starting yesterday after the update. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397706/ubuntus-firefox-webbrowser-error. Installed the flatpak-firefox. No problems with downloads (but some other things).

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Downloads fix:

1. go to `about:config` in the URL bar
2. search for `browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel`
3. Change to `false`

It appears to have been a Mozilla "improvement".

Comment: some "improvement".