# Ubuntu's Firefox Webbrowser error

Tags: 20.04, bash, kubuntu, firefox

After updating the firefox webbrowser on March 14 it creates an error. In the titlebar it says 'bash - dpkg has an error with the post-installation script'. I installed the flatpak-version, but that resets my theme when I close it and has addons I cannot remove. I cannot set it as default browser either. (If I want a browser without a theme I would use Midori!)

So what I want to do is get the older Ubuntu-version back to avoid those problems. Is that a good idea ( security )? If so, how do I do that?

Or is it possible to repair the Ubuntu-version? 
See picture for what happens.[image]
Update 220322
I installed Firefox 98.0.2 (64-bit) (Canonical/Ubuntu-version) succesfully. Problems solved, so I thought. (Skipped a version.) But after restart the same problem occured.
I use a HP Envy 17-CE1000 with
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-35-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I looked at this solution:[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241362/fix-package-post-installation-script-subprocess-returned-error-exit-status-10-fo). 
`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/*brave-browser*`
`sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 com.brave.brave-browser`
`sudo apt -f install` 
and changed it to
`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/firefox*`
`sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 firefox`
`sudo apt -f install`
And now my `Ubuntu-firefox` is starting up just fine. I keep the `flatpak-firefox` as well (as a backup, although I also have `Midori`).
Thank you for reading the question. I leave it posted, as it might help other community members.
The bash error has gone, but the behavior (completely see-through) stays the same. I guess I have to wait for another update (purging and reinstalling didn't help either).
I will use the flatpak-version for now.