# Why was the Breeze theme installed as a flatpak in my system?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, themes, flatpak

The Breeze theme is a standard theme installed on Kubuntu 20.04.2. Why was a flatpak version of the theme installed in my system?

I want to use flatpaks as little as possible. Is there a `.deb` version of the Breeze theme that can replace the flatpak one?

Not that I use it, but unfortunately, it seems to be deeply integrated into the system. So it seems unwise to uninstall it.

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ flatpak list --show-details --app --runtime

    Name     Description      Application ID    Version  Branch Arch   Origin  Installation Ref                                               Active commit Latest commit Installed size Options
    Freedes… Shared libraries …desktop.Platform 21.08.13 21.08  x86_64 flathub system       org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08             aded519497b3  -             562,7 MB       system,…
    Mesa     Mesa - The 3D G… …tform.GL.default 21.3.8   21.08  x86_64 flathub system       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/21.08  ebb00f0466df  -             387,5 MB       system,…
    Intel                     …form.VAAPI.Intel          21.08  x86_64 flathub system       org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/21.08 a9b80c202edb  -              46,4 MB       system,…
    ffmpeg-…                  …form.ffmpeg-full          21.08  x86_64 flathub system       org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg-full/x86_64/21.08 6994ee218e7e  -              10,8 MB       system,…
    openh264 OpenH264 Video … …latform.openh264 2.1.0    2.0    x86_64 flathub system       org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/2.0      73f998362a6f  -             778,2 kB       system,…
    GNOME A… Shared librarie… …g.gnome.Platform          42     x86_64 flathub system       org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/42                      d240597586ac  -             754,7 MB       system,…
    Breeze … Breeze GTK them… …Gtk3theme.Breeze          3.22   x86_64 flathub system       org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Breeze/x86_64/3.22              60cb5ba476b4  -             404,0 kB       system,…
    Inkscape Vector tekenpak… …nkscape.Inkscape 1.1.2    stable x86_64 flathub system       org.inkscape.Inkscape/x86_64/stable               d854e2e539a5  -             267,8 MB       system,…
    Firefox  Fast, Private &… ….mozilla.firefox 100.0    stable x86_64 flathub system       org.mozilla.firefox/x86_64/stable                 37589d23e6a3  -             241,5 MB       system,…
```

I did install some KDE apps with 'discover'. Don't remember if they are using flatpak or not. I also installed Firefox Flatpak (because the standard Canonical FF had some issues (see [Ubuntu's Firefox Webbrowser error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397706/ubuntus-firefox-webbrowser-error)).

I also installed Inkscape from 'discover'. When I list the flatpaks, the Breeze theme is listed.

I run:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-41-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not have flatpak installed by default. Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: The breeze theme is not a flatpak. Kubuntu by default comes without flatpak support (because it is a competitor to snaps). On my system (now on 22.04 it is a .deb and i am quite sure it was also on 20.04).

Comment: In case you installed kde apps as flatpak, they would pull the breeze theme as a flatpak package.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi So it pulled it as a flatpak while it was already installed as a .deb. That is just plain stupid. Unasked install things twice. When I installed the flatpak Firefox I explicitly choose the flatpak because of the troubles I had with the Canonical. If you put your last remark as an answer I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have installed some KDE apps via flatpak, and they pulled the breeze theme as a dependency.

In case you have already removed those KDE flatpak apps and the breeze theme is still there, you can remove them with `flatpak remove --unused`.